# Is a countable product of open intervals homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\omega$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Fix countably many intervals $(a_i,b_i) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and let $\pi_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (a_i,b_i)$ be their Cartesian product with the product topology.

Question: is $\pi_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (a_i,b_i)$ homeomorphic to $\pi_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$ with the product topology?

I know that there exists a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and any open interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$, so would it be possible to define a homeomorphism between the product spaces by making a function such that, when projected to the $i$th component, is simply the homeomorphism between $(a_i,b_i)$ and $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Why do you think the homeomorphism you're proposing would not work?

Comment: @Taladris I was worried about openness and continuity. An open set in the infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{R}$ contains a product of open sets, finitely many which are not equal to $\mathbb{R}$. I think there would be a homeomorphism between any two open intervals (since they're both homeomorphic to the real line), so the inverse image of the open set would contain a product of either $(a_i,b_i)$ or open subsets of $(a_i,b_i)$. Is this correct? I suppose the proof that it is an open mapping would work the same way.

Comment: Actually, you only need to prove the following lemma: if $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of continuous functions from $X_i$ to $Y_i$, $i\in I$, then the function $f$ from $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ into $\Pi_{i\in I}Y_i$ defined by $f( (a_i)_{i\in I} )=( f_i(a_i) )_{i\in I}$ is continuous.

Using this lemma twice, together with the fact that in your case $f$ is clearly bijective (from set theory), means that $f$ is an homeomorphism.